# Mysql query time issue?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

Hi so I am trying to grab all records that fall between  10 minutes ago and now using this query.

```
SELECT task_id, task_title, task_assigned_phone_number, task_assigned_name, task_assigned_user_id, task_guest_id, task_creator_id
FROM TASKS
WHERE task_reminder IS NOT NULL AND
      task_reminder > ? AND
      task_reminder <= ? AND
      reminded = 0 AND
      task_complete = 0
ORDER BY task_reminder ASC";
```

I have the schema and SQL query up on sqlfiddle and as you run the query you can see 0 records fall in place. The times I included where based on new Data().getTime() on nodejs. What should I be doing? I tried new Date()..toUTCString() but still having issues.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a361/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using Unix epochs for a `timestamp` column.  I would expect a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE t.task_reminder IS NOT NULL AND
      t.task_reminder > now() - interval 10 minute AND
      t.reminded = 0 AND
      t.task_complete = 0
```

You might also need `t.task_reminder < now()`, if you have future reminders.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1575bf/1) is a sql<>fiddle.  Note that the data in the table needs to change to demonstrate this.

Comment: Can you update it in the sqlfiddle and send me the new link -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a361/9 I tried it like so and doesnt seem to work

Comment: copy and paste line one and two to your where clause.

Comment: It is in my where clause... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your timestamp format. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TASKS 
WHERE task_reminder IS NOT NULL 
AND task_reminder > '2019-09-17 00:00:00' 
AND task_reminder <= '2019-09-18 00:00:00' 
AND reminded = 0 
AND task_complete = 0 
ORDER BY task_reminder ASC;
```